# App Engine: Default Third Party libraries availabe in Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine

I have just downloaded App Engine Python SDK 1.9.4 and went to the `google_appengine/lib` directory. It contains a lot more libraries such as `CherryPy`, `simplejson`, `requests` that are not mentioned in the documentation  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

This is a bit surprising. Is the documentation not updated or I'm seeing these libraries just on local machine?